# Как подключиться к удаленной БД sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Можно ли подключиться удаленно к БД Sqlite3 через python, и если да то как?

Comment: Можно. sqlite подключается как файл. Соответственно, смонтировав удалённый хост можно подключить файл с него. Способ монтирования зависит от целевой и конечной системы (Windows, Linux, etc.. ?).

Comment: ну вот как указать путь например к сайту я уж думаю не  так pro = sqlite3.connect('сайт')

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич это не рекомендовано. https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html. Лучше сменить DBMS.

Comment: опишите какую задачу решаете. Почему вы думаете, что подключение к удалённой sqlite БД будет решением в вашем случае? *"SQLite competes with fopen()."*

Comment: задача заключается в том что вон на сервере есть так сказать вопросы по тесту (в БД) нужно чтобы когда пользователь заходил в прогу все вопросы которые храняться в бд выводились на форму. Ну или через прогу так же вводил данные в БД

Comment: @Dmitry не рекомендовано - да, но не запрещено :)

Comment: @Дмитрий информацию необходимую для ответа помещайте в сам вопрос (есть кнопка [edit]). "когда пользователь заходил в прогу" -- что это означает? Если вы подразумеваете, что человек в браузере на страничку заходит, а ваша задача реализовать web-приложение, которое эту страничку формирует, то sqlite БД лучше чтоб локально относительно web-приложения была, хотя может работать и с сетевыми файловыми системами (сами пользователи могут быть где угодно).

Comment: Есть программа написанная с помощью tkinter в ней реализована подключение БД sqlite локально она работает , но мне нужно БД перенести на удаленный сервер и чтобы при работе с этой программой(не на сайте) мне выводились данные от  удаленной БД

Comment: @Дмитрий - целевая ОС вовсе не праздный вопрос в данном случае

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич из ссылки что я давал раньше: SQLite will work over a network filesystem, but because of the latency associated with most network filesystems, performance will not be great. Also, file locking logic is buggy in many network filesystem implementations (on both Unix and Windows). If file locking does not work correctly, two or more clients might try to modify the same part of the same database at the same time, resulting in corruption. - Общий смысл: (1) из-за задержек производительность будет не лучщей (2) из-за багов в блокироке файлов можно поломать БД.

Comment: @Dmitry согласен. Всё на совести разработчика. Кэш, блокировки и.т.д. Это вопрос второй, и отдельный!

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич В том то и дело, что там говорится о багах в блокировке фалов в самих сетевых файловых системах. У меня просто весь перевод в коммент не влез. Тут уже от разработчика БД ни чего не зависит.

Comment: @Dmitry Если знать, как это работает - порчи данных можно избежать... Но познания и принятые меры должны быть довольно глубокими :) Именно поэтому, мой вопрос про ОС например не случаен и в этом ключе.

Comment: @Дмитрий в этом случае ваша GUI программа  может данные писать/читать, делая запросы к серверу, который рядом с базой данных (базу данных в интернет открывать не стоит), к примеру, используя REST API или GraphQL.